# Why ng-init variable not overriden by controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, ng-init

I am new to angular.

Why my ng-init variable is not overriding in controller?

```
<div ng-init="name='Emmad'" ng-controller="TodoController as todoCtrl" >
     <my-name></my-name>
</div>
```

my controller is:

```
App.controller('TodoController',['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.name = "Zahid";
}]);
```

and my directive is :

```
App.directive('myName',function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        template: '<b>{{name}}<b>'
    }
});
```

The output is always:

```
Emmad
```

It should be 'zahid' because I am using the directive in controller and controller will override the name variable.

Questions:

1-Why its not 'zahid'?

2-If I put breakpoint on

```
$scope.name = "Zahid";
```

I don't see 'name' variable in $scope why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17104639/ng-init-ng-controller-strange-behavior-in-the-controllers-scope

Comment: you need to look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/33285651/2435473 where I mention exactly how `ng-init` work

Comment: So its the priority that matters. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Pankaj Parkar for detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33285606/inject-variables-via-ng-init-to-controller/33285651#33285651) and below is the excerpt of answer.

Technically, what happening is that the ng-init directive gets evaluated after the `ng-controller` function gets registered. That's why initialized values from the `ng-init` are not available inside the controller.

Basically, the reason behind `ng-controller` getting called first is the priority. If you look at the priority, the `ng-init` directive has 450 & the priority option of directive, where ng-controller directive has 500, while compiling the directive from the DOM AngularJS sorts them as per priorities. Thus ng-controller gets executed first.